# Gulp: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: gulp

I am using gulp to uglify, concat and compress my javasscripts. When i run **all.js** script on my website its give me below highlighted error. But if i don't compress and only concat and ugilfy everything works fine than. I don't know why its is giving me this error by compressing. For compressing i am using [jstuckey/gulp-gzip](https://github.com/jstuckey/gulp-gzip) module.

Browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('all_scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(['app/app.js', 'app/services/*.js', 'app/directives/*.js', 'app/components/**/*.js', 'app/routing_components/**/*.js'])
      .pipe(concat('all.js'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gzip()) //by commenting this all.js works fine
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

**Note:** In my directory app/all.js.gz occur after running gulp all_scripts. But in browser its giving me error.

In browser for all.js, i am getting network response with "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br" and status 200:

```
    P�{P�e��*�y?R�%'S�׏���+D0�՞����v_�l��/H�
���|�! ��MrX��� O�Vg��d�K�<����}ݑ�QP��y#(R�6�e�
�C�q����+1S��Y�D�鳑����G�)_"@3Y&��I�P�w@}�O�w�h[���;���!pWʂl�[�8T���R��WqI^�E�O�u�6�����������Q̩��bS��s  @b�d�8>�یl�/ƛm�
�02�믔�c3:η�̧eM�����zU�Q����,ζ�1��֣b�P��,�mR�\@����+G��Q�    �U�9J��`]+�˺�TK����,=��f�(�O����y��C�N/�l�STS݁�P-�I���9�"#��
$�G�^͡�P=�j�
~/�!V㖣'�b�X���j
��,^F��{��6�u�y6ۢL2��b�*y�)��   ��r��C��I?�f�2re��,T�b� T��(�   ��$`[Z�u�Z�$�H|
�t��S7C
���R]Z�(|p��؄��S4�#]AZW�
```

Comment: Have you included `var gzip = require('gulp-gzip');` in your gulp script?

Comment: Yes, i have include at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like gzip is working fine, but your browser may not be decoding the compressed file because (I guess) your headers arent set correctly.

You need these:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

See more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding

Comment: Request header: Accept:*/*, Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: `Accept-Encoding` != `Content-Encoding`